# Dynamically getting a list of standard library python packages names

Tags: python, python-import

I'd like to get a list of names of all standard lib packages.

By this, I mean those listed on I thought of parsing https://docs.python.org/3/library/:
strings `name` for which

```py
__import__(name)
```

`sys.builtin_module_names` looked promising, but that's not it.

I thought of parsing `~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/` or https://docs.python.org/3/library/, but surely there's a better way!

## Addendum

For those who need an [X for a Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): I'm statically navigating the imports of packages to analyze them -- namely, to see what third party packages are used, what standard libs, with what frequency, etc.

Comment: Why?  That's not a useful piece of information.  You can glob through each directory in `sys.path`, but what will you do with this information?

Comment: ever-valid to find XY problems, but a goal need not be useful to be interesting

Comment: @TimRoberts, glob(b)ing through `sys.path` would give me a superset of importable names, including non-standard library ones, wouldn't it? As to the X to my Y... I'll add that to my question to avoid XY patrons.

Comment: The problem is that Python's flexibility has made this someone difficult to determine.  The answer is very different on Windows, Linux, and MacOS, and the answer changes if virtual environments are involved.  The canonical Linux source is `/usr/lib/python/3.8`, and if I were you, that's where I'd go.  You could also scan through `sys.path` and eliminate entries that referenced site-specific locations.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was going for, but seemed like a convoluted way to do it. Might as well I just scrape and parse all `https://docs.python.org/VERSION/library/` pages and write my own package to get this information. At least that would be more accurate.

Comment: Note that another (less clunky than globing, but still clunky) solution is to use `pkgutil.iter_modules()` and filter out the third party modules. But for my purposes, I just parsed the html, made one list per python version, and exposed through python variable. I'll publish this now and answer my own question (but wait for better solutions before marking mine).

Comment: Scraped data published here: https://github.com/i2mint/unbox/tree/master/unbox/data/standard_lib_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will post my solution here, but will wait to see if there's better before accepting it as *the* answer.

Install [`unbox`](https://pypi.org/project/unbox/) and do this:

```py
from unbox import builtin_module_names
```

This should give you a set a names for the python version of your environment (2.7 and 3.5-3.9 supported).

To get these, I parsed the list out of `https://docs.python.org/{version}/library/` html pages and filtered out those that were not importable (from 3.8). You can verify that all the names are importable by doing:

```py
for name in builtin_module_names:
    _ = importlib.import_module(name)
```

These names are contained in the package's data folder (as .csv files) and can be found [here on github](https://github.com/i2mint/unbox/tree/master/unbox/data/standard_lib_names).

Note that you won't find all modules there -- only those that are (1) documented on said page **and** importable. For example, easter eggs such as `this` and `antigravity` won't be listed. You can find them in the larger `scanned_standard_lib_names` set, obtained by scanning local files:

```py
from unbox import scanned_standard_lib_names
assert scanned_standard_lib_names.issuperset({'this', 'antigravity'})
```

Comment: How did you obtain the list of modules? For example `this` is missing.

Comment: You're absolutely right -- I left a gap in my text where I meant to paste the link of where I parsed the data from. I now edited the answer, and included more information about where to find your easter eggs (`this`, `antigravity`...). You can find the script that I used to acquire, parse, and save the data [here](https://github.com/i2mint/unbox/blob/master/unbox/_acquire_builtin_names.py).